# Dynamically Added Chosen List not styling properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-chosen

I'm using ajax to get the HTML for a partial view which contains a drop-down list which I want styled with the Chosen jQuery plugin. The first one I add dynamically is styled properly, however all the others become links and do not get proper styling/functionality.

After adding in the row, I use:

```
$(".chosen").last().css('width', '150px').chosen();
```

The element does begin to get styled properly but it doesn't quite do it right. Here's the output.

```
<div id="SelectedRate_chzn" class="chzn-container" style="width: 150px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-default">
        <span>Select an Option</span>
        <div><b></b></div>
    </a>
    <div class="chzn-drop" style="left:-9000px;">
        <div class="chzn-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <ul class="chzn-results"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think anything is wrong with my partial view but if you need something else, comment below.

Comment: can u paste u code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can't really do that because I'm making an ajax request which I can't really simulate there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question when adding records through a dialog to an existing form and I managed to do this as follows:

after a successfull ajax call, I add a **new option to the original select element** and trigger the **liszt:updated** event to have chosen re-read the select element and update itself.

For example: 
the ajax call returns the new contact data to be added as json string

```
{ id:123, label:'new contact name' }
```

Append a new option to the select:

```
$('select#contact_id').append('<option value='+data.id+'>'+data.label+'</option>')
```

Trigger the event (you can chain it to the previous call)

```
$('select#contact_id').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Hope this gets you going!

Kind regards